# Очистка коллекции в MongoDB раз в сутки на NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, telegram-bot

Всем привет. Я создаю Telegram бота. Ему на протяжении дня пользователи скидывают ссылки, он их сохраняет и обрабатывает всячески. Потом раз в сутки, например в 5:00, коллекция c ссылками в MongoDB должна очистится. Как этого можно добиться? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule или 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался сам, вот код

```
setInterval(() => {
 mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('links', (err, results) => {
    console.log(results)
 })
```

}, 86400000)

Через 24 часа будет удалена коллекция `links`, `results` вернет `true`

UPD: еще можно через cron

```
    cron.schedule('0 5 * * *', () => {
  mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('links', (err, results) => {
        console.log(results)
     })
})
```

Будет удалятся коллекция `links` каждый день в 4 ночи, на сколько я понял.